# How to set BackGroundImage to Crystal Reports?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, overlay

I am using Crystal Reports, i want to set a background image to my report and i am aware of that and i set it by using OVERLAY option on **section expert**. But it comes like this
[image]

how do i get the background image for the Next items. All the matter is in **DETAIL Section** the image is in **Page Header Section**. how can i do this. Can anybody help me on this.

the above one is a A4 sheet in one page it prints three records. the image is coming for one record only. it is not coming for remaining records

Answer (score 1):

hi you can do this thing by inserting **GROUP HEADER SECTION** for the Field Name then it works.

Answer (score 1):

Just Insert Picture.

Crystal Report ----> Right Click -----> Insert Picture